# Classpath for taskdef?

Tags: ant, classpath, taskdef

I am defining a new task in Ant.
I exported it as a jar and added to my buildfile:

```
<taskdef classname="X" classpath="Y.jar"/>
```

The problem is that this fails at runtime.
It tells me it didn't find the class.
By adding the jar to the classpath, it is corrected.

My question is: Is there a way that I can refer to my jar from the Ant buildfile, without changing the classpath?

Answer (score 11):

If you know the path of your jar, inside ant script you can define the classpath for your own task.

```
<taskdef name="myTaskName" classname="com.myorg.myclass">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="pathToMyJar.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'm assuming that you looked at the [doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) for `taskdef`, which just shows the task name and implementing class. However, `taskdef` subclasses `typedef`, and if you look at the [doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html) for the latter you'll see that there's also a `classpath` attribute.

**HOWEVER**, using this attribute means that your ant scripts are tied to a particular environment; they aren't very portable. A far better approach is to pass the classpath into Ant, using the `-lib` [invocation option](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options).

Comment: And if you're using a `CLASSPATH` environment variable, don't. Delete it from your environment setup, and get into the habit of specifying classpaths explicitly. Because otherwise, you'll find yourself with a hard-to-debug problem where a library gets loaded from your classpath and you don't expect it. Or someone else can't run your code because s/he doesn't have the same `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: I don't see why this is _a far better approach_. Specifying the classpaths with the `-lib` option just makes the user aware of those paths. You still need to tell the user where to look for them (for instance, in a readme, help file or an echoed message). Or you can decide to restructure your project directory hierarchy to include those libs in a specific subdir, becoming "environment-independent." A build script should take care of these details and ideally produce a sensible object with the default `ant` invocation.