# Ant Replacing a specific occurrence in xml

Tags: xml, ant, replace

I have xml like following and I want to change a specific occurrence of a value using Ant ( tried replaceregexp but didnt help much as it finds multiple occurrences , replace also replaces multiple occurrences) and we dont have xmltask integrated.

```
<databases>
 <database>
    <server>mssql_1</server>
    <port>1433</port>
   <sid_instance>foobar</sid_instance>
   <path></path>
   <hostuser>sa</hostuser>
   <hostpwd>password</hostpwd>
 </database>
<database>
  <server>oracle_1</server>
  <port>1521</port>
  <sid_instance>foobar</sid_instance>
  <path>C:\\oracle\\oradata\\foobar</path>
  <hostuser>system</hostuser>
  <hostpwd>password</hostpwd>
 </database>
</databases>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would plug in [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) since this is *precisely* what it's designed to do! Can't you just load it into (say) your home dir and provide a classpath reference as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4511337/12960) ?

(speaking as the author of XMLTask)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that [this link](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html#replacing-xml) help you. It´s explains how you can do this using the `xmlTask`.